# How to display algolia search results in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, algolia

I want to populate a table with algolia search result. I have this html

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>quantity</th>
          <th>Status</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Fax</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

   <tbody id="hits">
   </tbody>

  </table>

<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
        <tr id="hit">
        <td>
            <div class="round-img">
                <a href=""><img src="images/avatar/4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>${{VendorName}}</td>
        <td><span>iBook</span></td>
        <td><span>456 pcs</span></td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Done</span></td>
         <td><span>${{Active}}</span></td>
        <td><span>${{Vendortype}}</span></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

and this is my js script

```
 search.addWidget(
 instantsearch.widgets.hits({
  container: '#hits',
  templates: {
  item: document.getElementById('hit-template').innerHTML,
  empty: "We didn't find any results for the search <em>\"{{query}}\"</em>"
    }
    })
  );

search.start();
```

the search is working but the table are not being properly populated. this is what is being displayed

[image: result view]

What am I doing wrongly and how can I fix this that it is properly populated on the table?

Comment: What isn't populating? It's hard to tell from the picture. It seems the table is populating with data....is it not?

Comment: @KevinJantzer it's populating but its all on the first column instead of it being spread all under the names

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue?

Comment: @jone2 I had the same issue and actually had to go with a custom connector with vanilla JS (check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887949/customising-algolia-instantsearch-searchbox-and-results?rq=1). Right now I am trying to find a solution when using Vue instant search :)